How does one prove without the axiom of choice that the product of a collection of nonempty well-ordered sets is nonempty?
Suppose $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}$ is an indexed family of nonempty well-ordered sets, where $X_{\alpha}=(E_{\alpha},\le_{\alpha})$ for each $\alpha$. It seems intuitively obvious that we can prove, without the axiom of choice, that the product $\prod_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}E_{\alpha}$ is nonempty. The proof that immediately comes to mind is to define the function $f:\mathcal A\to\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}E_{\alpha}$ by $f(\alpha)=\min X_{\alpha}$, where $\min X_{\alpha}$ denotes the minimum of $X_{\alpha}$ with respect to the order $\le_{\alpha}$. However, I'm not sure exactly which axioms from $\mathsf{ZF}$ allow us to define the function $f$. That is, I'm not sure how to prove, using the axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone, that there exists a function $f:\mathcal A\to\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}E_{\alpha}$ such that for all $\alpha\in\mathcal A$ and $y\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}E_{\alpha}$,
$$
(\alpha,y)\in f\implies (y\in E_{\alpha})\land(\forall z\in E_{\alpha}(y\le_{\alpha}z)) \, .
$$
How would one do this? I suppose one could try applying the comprehension schema to the product $\mathcal A\times\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}E_{\alpha}$ in some way, but I'm not clear on the details.

I assume you mean "an indexed family of nonempty well-ordered sets"?

@NaïmFavier: Yes, thanks for the correction.

I am not sure why you need to define such a function.  The element $\langle \min X_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha\in \mathcal A}$ is an element of the product.  Therefore the product is nonempty.

@MikhailKatz: The Cartesian product of an indexed family of sets is defined as a certain collection of functions from the index set. The element which you speak of is the function $f$ in my post, at least under the usual set-theoretic definitions.

If you think of a function as a set via its graph, then the fact that you can pass from a formula to the underlying set is the Axiom of Separation.  You don't seem to be using much else.

Yes, this is just comprehension/separation. Take $f$ to be the set of all $(\alpha,x)\in \mathcal A\times \bigcup_{\alpha\in \mathcal A}E_\alpha$ such that $x$ is the $<\alpha$-least element of $E\alpha.$
